# What type of perturbation am I considering here?

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-biology

I need help with the last part of the following question:

> The number density of a population of amoebae is $n(\mathbf{x}, t)$. The amoebae exhibit chemotaxis and are attracted to high concentrations of a chemical which has concentration $a(\mathbf{x}, t)$. The equations governing $n$ and $a$ are
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> & \frac{\partial n}{\partial t}=\alpha n\left(n_0^2-n^2\right)+\nabla^2 n-\nabla \cdot(\chi(n) n \nabla a), \\
> & \frac{\partial a}{\partial t}=\beta n-\gamma a+D \nabla^2 a
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> where the constants $n_0, \alpha, \beta, \gamma$ and $D$ are all positive.
> (i) Give a biological interpretation of each term in these equations and discuss the sign of $\chi(n)$.
> (ii) Show that there is a non-trivial (i.e. $a \neq 0, n \neq 0$ ) steady-state solution for $n$ and $a$, independent of $\mathbf{x}$, and show further that it is stable to small disturbances that are also independent of $\mathbf{x}$.
> (iii) Consider small spatially varying disturbances to the steady state, with spatial structure such that $\nabla^2 \psi=-k^2 \psi$, where $\psi$ is any disturbance quantity. Show that if such disturbances also satisfy $\partial \psi / \partial t=p \psi$, where $p$ is a constant, then $p$ satisfies a quadratic equation, to be derived. By considering the conditions required for $p=0$ to be a possible solution of this quadratic equation, or otherwise, deduce that instability is possible if
> $$
> \beta \chi_0 n_0>2 \alpha n_0^2 D+\gamma+2\left(2 D \alpha n_0^2 \gamma\right)^{1 / 2},
> $$
> where $\chi_0=\chi\left(n_0\right)$.

I have already done parts (i) and (ii). I am however struggling with part (iii), in particular, I do not know what perturbations I am considering. I tried

\begin{align*}
\tilde{n}   (x,t) = n_0 +  \epsilon \psi (x,t) \quad \tilde{a} (x,t)= \frac{\beta  n_0}{\gamma } +  \epsilon   \phi (x,t)
\end{align*}
with $\psi$ and $\phi$ with the structure as given in the question. Als note that $(n_0, \frac{\beta n_0}{\gamma })$ is the steady state. The two linearisations then give
\begin{align*}
\phi (p +  2a (n_0)^{2} +  k^{2}) = n_0 k^{2} \psi
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\phi (p +  \gamma  +  k^{2} D) = \beta  \psi.
\end{align*}
This makes no sense given the question. I think I am missundering what perturbations I should be considering. Could someone help?

**Question**: What perturbations should I be considering?